# How Do I Unhook This Parent Theme Function?

Tags: functions, filters, hooks, actions, child-theme

In a parent theme I have a function like this, that removes hyperlinks from comments:

```
function preprocess_comment_remove_url( $commentdata ) {

  //some code...

    return $commentdata;

}
add_filter( 'preprocess_comment' , 'preprocess_comment_remove_url' );
```

I want to unhook this function, as I want to use links in my comments. I can't seem to unhook it. I tried different things. This is my most recent approach:

```
function child_remove_parent_functions() {
    remove_filter( 'preprocess_comment', 'preprocess_comment_remove_url');
}
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'child_remove_parent_functions' );
```

But that also doesn't work. How do I unhook the parent function?

Answer (score 0):

`wp_loaded` would fire too early - you can't remove a hook before it's been added.

I'd try adding your own hook with a higher priority, at the same level as the parent's hook. That is, not inside an action.

`add_filter( 'preprocess_comment' , 'my_preprocess_comment_function', 5 );`

Then within *your* function, remove the parent function:

```
function my_preprocess_comment_function( $commentdata ) {
    remove_filter( 'preprocess_comment', 'preprocess_comment_remove_url' );
// Do anything else you need to do
return $commentdata;
}
```